# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Orders_Employees"

Tags: vb.net, constraints, foreign-key-relationship, northwind

I've been working with an Online Ordering Application in an example of Building web applications called OnlineOrdering. Found it in Mastering Visual Basic 2010 book Chapter 20. Every thing works till I get to the Cart.aspx web form step of Check Out, ordersAdapter.Update(orders). I'll appreciate if some one has work with it.

```html
Protected Sub bttnCheckOut_Click(ByVal sender As Object,
                                     ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles bttnCheckOut.Click
        Dim productsAdapter As New NorthwindTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter
        Dim products As Northwind.ProductsDataTable = productsAdapter.GetData

        Dim ordersAdapter As New NorthwindTableAdapters.OrdersTableAdapter
        Dim orders = ordersAdapter.GetData

        Dim orderDetailsAdapter As New NorthwindTableAdapters.Order_DetailsTableAdapter
        Dim orderDetails = orderDetailsAdapter.GetData

        Dim order = orders.AddOrdersRow(Session("userId"), CInt(Session("employeeId")),
                                        Date.Now.Date, Date.Now.AddDays(7).Date,
                                        Date.MinValue, 1,
                                        Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing,
                                        Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
        order.SetShippedDateNull()
        ordersAdapter.Update(orders)
        orders.AcceptChanges()
        For Each orderDetail In queryResult
            Dim product = products.FindByProductID(orderDetail.ProductID)
            orderDetails.AddOrder_DetailsRow(order, product, orderDetail.UnitPrice,
                                             orderDetail.Quantity, orderDetail.Discount)
        Next
        orderDetailsAdapter.Update(orderDetails)
        orderDetails.AcceptChanges()
        Response.Redirect("Confirmation.aspx")

    End Sub
```

It breaks in code line ordersAdapter.Update(orders) and receive this message :The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Orders_Employees". The conflict occurred in database 
"Northwind", table "dbo.Employees", column 'EmployeeID'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: It looks like the employee ID in question doesn't yet exist. If the orders table is connected to some employee table via foreign key constraint, and there is no row for the employee in question in the employee table, you'd get an error like this.

Comment: You are in the right path. At the end of the example the author writes this: "If you inspect the code in Listing 20.11 carefully, you will see that there are a few hardcoded features. Namely, since I did not implement the login feature, I assigned the value ALFKI to userId and used it when creating the order. ....". Page 890.

Comment: ... Once the Login feature is implemented, a real
user ID can be assigned to the userId variable.
Since the purpose of the online ordering application is to have users create their own
orders without employee intervention, the employeeId variable is assigned a value of 10. ..... "

Comment: This employee ID does not exist in the Northwind database, but you can generate it by adding a row to the Employees table and naming the user Online Ordering Application."

Comment: I've been working in this last part but don't know how to do it.

Comment: It's usually an Access or SQL Server database. You just have to go into the database and manually add the row...

Comment: I'll do it and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: 1. Add the row manually and run the app but I get ERROR 404

Comment: 2. The key issue is in the Session variable line. Doing more research found this : "If you are setting up a site that will employ identification of its users, require some form of authentication, and/or offer customization of settings, it is a good idea to use Microsoft’s membership system, which is available through the Web Site Administration tool and the Login controls.". It gets more complicated than I thought.

Comment: 3. Session variables in code:

Comment: Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object,
                            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Set to real user Id after implementing Login functionality
        'Session("userId") = "ALFKI"
        Session("userId") = "ALFKI"
        'Add "Online Employee" to database and set employeeId accordingly
        Session("employeeId") = 11
        GenerateOrder()
        lblTotal.Text = total.ToString()
        gwCart.DataSource = queryResult
        gwCart.DataBind()
    End Sub

Comment: 3.1. In sample found this: "there are a few hardcoded features. Namely, since I did not implement the login feature, I assigned the value ALFKI
to userId and used it when creating the order. Once the Login feature is implemented, a real user ID can be assigned to the userId variable.
."

Comment: 3.2. "Since the purpose of the online ordering application is to have users create their own orders without employee intervention, the employeeId variable is assigned a value of 10. This employee ID does not exist in the Northwind database, but you can generate it by adding a row to the  Employees table and naming the user Online Ordering Application"

Comment: Comments; 3, 3.1., 3.2. might help to help solving this problem, but I don't know how.